# Append h264 stream to m3u8 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

I use ffmpeg with the segments options to write from a h264 fifo to a hls live but the computer may have to restart.
So I want to restart the livestream where it ended.

Here is my ffmpeg command:

````
ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -r 15 -i 1/live.m3u8 \
 -f s16le -i /dev/zero -r:a 48000 -ac 2 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -r 15 \
 -f segment \
 -segment_time 7 \
 -segment_format mpegts \
 -segment_list 0/live.m3u8 \
 -segment_list_flags live \
 -segment_list_type m3u8 \
 -initial_offset -9 \
 -strict 2 $2/%08d.ts < /dev/null```
````